# How to copy a transparent PNG file to iPad from a Mac

Tags: photos.app, file-transfer, image-capture

When copying a PNG file with transparent background to an iPad or an iPhone using an application like iTunes, the image is copied to the device but the transparent background turns white.

I have tried emailing the PNG file as an attachment. While it retains its transparency, I'm looking for faster ways of transferring such a file?

I'd welcome all types of answers, such as if anyone has tried using a file sharing software like Dropbox. I'm looking for a solution where the image with its transparency will be available on the device as fast as possible.

Comment: Which photo software did you try for transfering?

Comment: ITunes, by connecting device to mac

Comment: You can try AirDrop!

Comment: In which app is the PNG stored on the iPad/iPhone?

Comment: Png file is a photo file. It is stored as photos in iPhone and iPad devices. It can be accessed in all apps if required.

Comment: AirDrop is probably one of the quickest, but you can also try installing an app like Documents by Readdle [https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/documents-by-readdle/id364901807?mt=8] or FileHub [https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/file-hub-powerful-intuitive-file-manager/id730843281?mt=8]. Then, on the device screen, go to *File Sharing* (in iTunes 12.7), select the app and drop the file there. The file is then instantly available on the corresponding app on your iPad or iPhone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any file transfer option that simply copies the file directly will suffice. This includes AirDrop and file syncing options such as Dropbox and Google Drive. I would personally recommend using AirDrop, as since it is transferred with a local ad-hoc Wi-Fi connection, it never needs to leave your local network and allows for fast transfer speeds of even very large files. Note that this will only work if your iOS and Mac devices meet [these requirements](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203106#tips).

The Apple support website offers [these instructions](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203106) for using AirDrop to send files to an iOS device:

> 1. Choose Go > AirDrop from the menu bar in the Finder. Or select
>      AirDrop in the sidebar of a Finder window.
> 2. The AirDrop window shows
>      nearby AirDrop users. Drag one or more items to the recipient's
>      image in the window, then click Send.
>
> Or use the Share feature:
>
> 1. Click the Share button, if available in your app. Or Control-click an item in the Finder, then choose Share from the shortcut menu.
> 2. The Share menu lists several sharing options. Choose AirDrop.
> 3. Select a recipient from the AirDrop sheet, then click Done.

Comment: I tried Airdrop, the file transferred with transparency. I.e. as a normal complete file.